# Overlay with scroll bar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working to make an overlay menu from one the [tutorials](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/02/06/fullscreen-overlay-effects/). It is a nice way of doing menu. Only problem i noticed is that when you have  large menu then you are not able to scroll down the page in page has less text as is case with [example one](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpOxKQ)

In second example i have lot of page text and still and when i scroll it scroll page text but not the overlay. You can noticed in background page scroll. [example two](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XmzEWm?editors=110)

How can i make only make overlay to scroll and not the actual page so that when in case i have marge menu then i over will scroll to length of menu

HTML CODE

```
<div class="container">

    <section>
        <p>Overlay fades in and menu rotates slightly in perspective. As seen on <a href="http://hugeinc.com">Huge</a></p>
        <p><button id="trigger-overlay" type="button">Open Overlay</button></p>
    </section>

</div><!-- /container -->
<!-- open/close -->
<div class="overlay overlay-hugeinc">
    <button type="button" class="overlay-close">Close</button>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Work 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Clients 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `overflow-y: scroll;` to your `.overlay` element and you will have a vertical scroll bar just on that element